# Splitting Web Page URL but Not URL After the Hash in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I tried getting the text after my URL like this "example.com/#!/THISPART" with the code below:

```
var webSplit = window.location.hash.split('/')[1];
```

And It works but if I supply another URL after like this "example.com/#!/https://example.com/" it gives this as output "https" which I don't want. I want the whole URL. Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: You could just remove the `#!/` like so `window.location.hash.replace('#!/','')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The actual problem is that your approach for the split is incorrect.

With your example `window.location.hash` return `#!/https://example.com/`. What you#re doing is splitting that element by `/` and using the second element of the result.

The result of the split would be 4 elements (`[ "#!", "https:", "", "example.com" ]`) and the second element would be just he `https:`. What you need to do, do fix it is either find an another delimiter or find another way to extract the URL.

With your current example you could `!/` for the split to get two elements back (`[ "#", "https://example.com" ]`) where the second one would be the whole URL, as long as it doesn't contain the string `!/`. Another appraoch would be to find the first occurrence of `http` from the left and take a substring from what position until the end of it.

Other answers show some different solution.

Comment: I tried that and it worked a few days ago, I forgot to post an answer about it on this question but you did it really well. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
window.location.hash.split('!/')[1]; // Outputs "https://example.com/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Meet REGEX.

```
var part = location.hash.replace(/#!\//, '');
```

That'll give you whatever's after `#!/`.

Comment: Doesn't work on `example.com/#!/THISPART` because of the extra `\/`

Comment: @JeremyThille works fine for me when I've tried it, it returned `THISPART`

Comment: No, it returns `!/THISPART`. There is no match for `#!/` in the test string.

Comment: @JeremyThille with your example of `example.com/#!/THISPART` `window.location.hash` will return `#!/THISPART` so there is `#!/` to match?

Comment: WTF? What did I smoke? My brain wasn't working well these past 10 minutes. Apologies, you're absolutely right.

Comment: @JeremyThille no problem, we all make mistakes. You was just making me question myself!

Answer (score 0):

```
var webSplit = window.location.split('/#!/')[1];
```

Output will be :: `https://example.com/` as ou want.

Comment: Actually, the output would be undefined. `window.location.hash` returns everything after the hash, so remove the first forward slash in the split

Comment: Ahh! my mistake.